# Eclipse not running any applications

Tags: c++, eclipse, launch

When I launch a C++ application locally on my Eclipse IDE the program automatically terminates, however, if I run the debugger instead of launching a local C++ application, it runs. Also if I open the executable on the Debug folder with the Windows console, it works. I even tried reinstalling Eclipse CDT. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the console isn't just closing after the program terminates? Obviously the windows console wont close itself after running a program. Not sure about the debug console, but I'm guessing it behaves in the same non-closing way for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: i'm just running a hello world program for testing purposes, and expects keyboard input before terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording makes me wonder, did you rebuild the Release version of the application? Did it rebuild without error. If you go to release folder and run the .exe directly outside of eclipse does it run? I would suspect the biggest difference between the Release and Debug versions would be the compiler optimization settings.